# Wait till all Observables are completed

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have few Observables like this one in my code.

```
this.server.doRequest().subscribe(response => console.log(response)
      error => console.log(error),
      () => {
        console.log('completed');
      });
```

There could be any number of these Observables,
so I need to write a function that checks if each Observable is done otherwise waits till each is finished.

I'm assuming I can create an array push every new Observable there and when it's completed remove it by index. But is it good solution?

Where I want to use it. For example I have a page where user upload photos any amount asynchronously and then he press Finish button. Once he pressed Finish button I need to wait till ALL dynamically created Observables are completed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use higher order observables for this, your exact use case will dictate the exact operator, but forkJoin seems a good candidate:

```
forkJoin(
  this.server.doRequest1(),
  this.server.doRequest2(),
  this.server.doRequest3(),
  this.server.doRequest4()
).subscribe(vals => console.log('all values', vals));
```

forkJoin won't emit till all innter observables have completed. making it the operator of choice for waiting for multiple observables to complete.  You can also feed it an array of observables.  There are multiple other operators that may fulfill your case too, such as concat, merge, combineLatest or a few others.

edit based on more details:

in the use case described in your update, you'll still want to use a higher order observable, but forkjoin is not what you want. you'll want to use a local subject to accomplish the goal as wanting to kick off each observable as it is selected and waiting for them all to be done complicates things a little (but not too much):

suppose you had a template like:

```
<button (click)="addPhoto()">Add Photo</button>

<button (click)="finish()">Finish</button>
```

where the add photo button gets the users photo and all that, and finish is your completion, you could have a component like this:

```
private addPhoto$ = new Subject();

constructor() {
  this.addPhoto$.pipe(
    mergeMap(() => this.uploadPhoto()),
  ).subscribe(
    (resp) => console.log('resp', resp),
    (err) => console.log('err', err),
    () => console.log('complete')
  );
}

private uploadPhoto() {
  // stub to simulate upload
  return timer(3000);
}

addPhoto() {
  this.addPhoto$.next();
}

finish() {
  this.addPhoto$.complete();
}
```

if you run this code, you'll see that the photo adds will emit in the subscribe handler as they complete, but complete will only fire once all the photo uploads have completed and the user has clicked finish.

here is a stackblitz demonstrating the functionality:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bsn6pz

Comment: Would doRequest2 execute while doRequest1 has not completed?

Comment: It's a good idea. But Observable creates dynamically. For example user click on button. How can I use dynamically created Observerable with forkJoin

Comment: @tgralex with forkJoin, all requests execute in parallel.  Other operators can go sequentially if needed.

Comment: @NickD pretty easily.  You might need to give a clearer example of what you're after

Comment: I updated my question with an example of what I try to build

Comment: do the photo uploads happen as they select photos or after they click finish?

Comment: Uploads happen once user select photo

Comment: So just push them into the array, and on submit forkJoin the array.

Comment: added a different set up to complete your stated goal. forkJoin is not the operator for this particular use case.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. One more question how can I pass arguments to uploadPhoto function?

Comment: when you call next on addPhoto$, do `addPhoto$.next(arg)`. then that will be passed as an argument to the mergeMap function like `mergeMap((arg) => this.uploadPhoto(arg))`

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a dictionary  (in javascript that would be a JSON with observable names as boolean properties) where you push each observable on "create" and a method which should execute on completion of each observable, which will iterate through that dictionary and if all completed do something.
That will ensure parallelism and final execution after all completed.

```
var requests = {
    doRequest1: false,
    doRequest2: false,
    doRequest3: false
};

var checkIfCAllCompleted = name => {
    requests[name] = true;
    for (var property in requests) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (!property) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    // all properties are true - do something here
    console.log("here");
}
this.server.doRequest1().then(() => checkIfCAllCompleted("doRequest1"));
this.server.doRequest2().then(() => checkIfCAllCompleted("doRequest2"));
this.server.doRequest3().then(() => checkIfCAllCompleted("doRequest3"));
```